# Async methods in swift ViewController delegates

Tags: swift, async-await, delegates, viewcontroller

I have a view (for the sake of the example, say an `NSOutlineView`). I assign a delegate to it and override a method like:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
    let data = ... some async call to fetch data
    let view = makeView(withData: data)
    return view
}
```

In the case that the fetch of data is from an async source, what is the best pattern to use here?

Comment: You need to make the delegate method itself `async`, otherwise how could you do async work in a sync method?

Comment: The signature of the delegate method shown here is supplied by Apple in the spec for NSOutlineView. My understanding is that I can't just add `async` to that, Apple would need to do it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If that method is not in your control, then indeed you cannot modify its type signature. As I've said before, you cannot make async calls in a synchronous method that has a return value, which return value depends on the result of the async method call. You need to rearchitect your code that the data is either ready by the time the delegate method is called or that you modify the returned view once the async method returns, but still return a view synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

A synchronous data source delegate method cannot return data retrieved from an `async` method.

So, it depends a little upon why you must `await`, in the first place:

1. If it is truly asynchronous (e.g., you need to fetch data from a remote web service, for example), then the idea is that you initiate the fetch of the data, return some dummy/empty view for now, and when the asynchronous request is done, you “reload” the control, triggering it to update the UI with the fetched data.
2. However, if your data source data method is `async` only because you happen to be crossing actor boundaries (e.g., your view is on the main actor, your view model is on its own actor), the answer is to refactor it so the called method is on the same actor.

   In practice, when interacting with legacy `UIKit` and `Cocoa` data source delegates, it is common to have our view models designated as `@MainActor`. That way, our view can interact with the data managed by the view model without an `async` call.

To be more precise in our answer, we need more information about the nature of the “some async call to fetch data” portion of the code snippet.